# Unreachable nodes in Akka Cluster Sharding

Tags: sharding, akka-cluster

I'm researching Akka Cluster Sharding, after read Akka documents and some topic in internet, I thought that when cluster has an unreachable node, only communication to shards on this node are interrupted. It means that messages are told to shards on it will be buffered and senders will receive a timeout response and messages are told to shards on other available nodes will be send and receive normally.
But when I tried to implement a cluster with 4 nodes, and then stopped service of one node, checked via Akka HTTP Management and confirm it was set unreachable, then I tested sending messages from an actor in an available node to an actor in other available node and received Timeout response.
So, anyone can help me to confirm when cluster has unreachable node, entire sharding system will not work normally, or just unreachable node?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From documentation:

> **Shard Coordinator State**
>
> The state of shard locations in the ShardCoordinator is persistent (durable) with Distributed Data or Persistence to survive failures. When a crashed or unreachable coordinator node has been removed (via down) from the cluster a new ShardCoordinator singleton actor will take over and the state is recovered. During such a failure period shards with known location are still available, while messages for new (unknown) shards are buffered until the new ShardCoordinator becomes available.

In this we have "During such a failure period shards *with known location* are still available", so when the `Shard Coordinator` is `unreachable` the whole cluster could not work properly.

For reference: [Shard Coordinator State in doc.akka.io](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/cluster-sharding.html?language=scala#shard-coordinator-state)

Comment: Thanks for you answer, after read it I tried again and know why I always receive timeout responses before, that cause I defined too many shards for just 4 nodes. Thanks again.